# Whats wrong with my hibernate transaction and session

Tags: java, hibernate

I have code as following.

```
class HibernateTest {

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final HibernateTest objHibernateTest = new HibernateTest();
    
    objHibernateTest.saveEmployeeDetails();
    
    objHibernateTest.saveEmployeeLeaves();
    
    objHibernateTest.saveEmployeePayment();
}

private void saveEmployeeDetails() {
    final Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.getTransaction().begin();//Begin Transaction
    Employee e = new Employee();//consider Employee have data
    session.update(e);
    session.flush();
    session.clear();
}

private void saveEmployeeLeaves() {
    final Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Employee e = new Employee();//consider Employee have data
    session.save(e);
    session.flush();
    session.clear();
}

private void saveEmployeePayment() {
    final Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Employee e = new Employee();//consider Employee have data
    session.save(e);
    session.flush();
    session.getTransaction().commit();//Commit Transaction
}
}
```

In above code i call `saveEmployeeDetails()` first where i get session and begin transation and then `flush() and clear()` for caching purpose.

I do same thing in `saveEmployeeLeaves()`.

In function `saveEmployeePayment()`, i perform something and save the employee details.

But in this scenario only the `Payment` details get stored in db not `Employee details` and `Leave details`

Why this so?

Comment: Please update your question to show where and why you think `Payment` and `Leave` objects would be persisted.

Comment: Most probably there are persistence declaration errors in your data model classes. Show the code for your data model classes.

Comment: @Rafael Which data model....?

Comment: I mean `Employee` class.

Comment: Consider that that employee object have correct values...

Answer (score 1):

You need to **commit** your transaction for every update. Updating in the last method call will not commit everything before. The scope of your `session` variable is restricted to the method block.

```
private void saveEmployeeDetails() {
    final Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.getTransaction().begin();//Begin Transaction
    Employee e = new Employee();//consider Employee have data
    session.update(e);
    session.flush();
    session.getTransaction().commit(); // Commit after update
    session.clear();
}

private void saveEmployeeLeaves() {
    final Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Employee e = new Employee();//consider Employee have data
    session.save(e);
    session.flush();
    session.getTransaction().commit(); //Commit after update
    session.clear();
}

private void saveEmployeePayment() {
    final Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Employee e = new Employee();//consider Employee have data
    session.save(e);
    session.flush();
    session.getTransaction().commit();//Commit Transaction
}
```

Comment: I have taken session from session factory so its single object i uses everywhere....

Comment: Your session variable is declared and initialized _inside_ the method. So the variable references are different in each call.